# Perfective of таскать

Tags: грамматика, вид, motion-verbs

Before asking my question, let me tell what I know about verbs of motion so far:

-For each verb of motion in English (ex.: *to go*) there are multiple verbs in Russian;

-Each nuance of motion verbs in Russian depends on the means of locomotion (on foot or by vehicle), and on the direction of movement (determined or undetermined).

-Moreover, there's the usual distinction between perfective and imperfective verbs.

-Furthermore, verbs of motion can be preceded by prefixes denoting destination, such as **при-** (denoting *arrival*), **вы-**, **у-** (denoting *exit*) or **в-** (denoting *entry*).

-While in each pair of unprefixed verbs of motion (determined and undetermined) both verbs are imperfective, adding a prefix converts both verbs to determined direction, being one perfective and the other imperfective.

So far so good. I believe I know the nuance of meaning of some groups, such as:

- ходить (undet. imp.), идти (det. imp.), пойти (det. pf.);
- ездить (undet. imp.), ехать (det. imp.), поехать (det. pf.);
- бе́гать (undet. imp.), бежа́ть (det. imp.), побежа́ть (det. pf.); etc.

Prefixed verbs have only one imperfective:

- входить (det. imp.), войти (det. pf.);
- въезжать (det. imp.), въехать (det. pf.);
- вбега́ть (det. imp.), вбежа́ть (det. pf.); etc.

Now, let's get into my doubt:

**Таска́ть** (undet.) / **тащи́ть** (det.) are a pair of imperfective verbs meaning "to drag". Since they are motion verbs, most likely *таскать* will remain imperfective when preceded by *в-*, *вы-*, *при-*. Whereas *тащить* will become the perfective counterpart of the prefixed verb.

However, is there a generic perfective prefix for *"тащить"*, neither denoting entry, nor exit, nor arrival? Like **"потащить"**?

Likewise, **лазить** (undet.) / **лезть** (det.) are the imperfective duo for "to climb". What's the generic perfective prefix for *"лезть"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the prefix **по-** mostly shows the beginning of the action, you can say it's the most generic meaning comparing to other prefixes. So **полезть** can be a safe variant like **потащить** and **потаскать**.

Answer (score 5):

> **Q:** most likely *таскать* will remain imperfective when preceded by *в-*,
>   *вы-*, *при-*. Whereas *тащить* will become the perfective counterpart of the prefixed verb.

**A:** With respect to this particular verb the opposite is true, it will be turned into *perfective*.

With prefix its *IMperfective* aspect will look like **`в-/вы-/при-тасК-ИВ-ать`**

Your statement however does hold true for other motion verbs `ходить`, `летать`, `бегать`, `плавать`, `ползать` etc.

- So `таскать`, though recognized as a motion verb, appears to be the only one to behave differently.

> **Q:** However, is there a generic perfective prefix for *"тащить"*, neither
>   denoting entry, nor exit, nor arrival? Like **"потащить"**?

**A:** Any prefix added to `тащить` turns it into *perfective*.

> **Q:** Likewise, **лазить** (undet.) / **лезть** (det.) are the imperfective
>   duo for "to climb". What's the generic perfective prefix for
>   *"лезть"*?

**A:** `Лазить` only becomes *perfective* with the prefixes **по-/из-/с-** (but this doesn't apply to every motion verb of its type).

In contrast, `лезть` becomes *perfective* regardless of the prefix like all motion verbs of its type.

Since prefixes are semantically significant, i guess there're no generic ones, everything hinges on the context.

---

In some cases of prefix **вы-** the aspect depends on the meaning signified with a stress

выход**И**ть<sup>imperf</sup> - в**Ы**ходить<sup>perf</sup>
вынос**И**ть<sup>imperf</sup> - в**Ы**носить<sup>perf</sup>
вывоз**И**ть<sup>imperf</sup> - в**Ы**возить<sup>perf</sup>
(not motion) вычит**А**ть<sup>imperf</sup> - в**Ы**читать<sup>perf</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Потащить - to start drag

Потаскать - to drag a bit around

Оттаскать - to drag around quite enough

Затаскать - to drag around up to changed condition

Comment: Утащить - to drag away from a rightful owner :)